# Update empty string to NULL in a html form

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm building a site in Laravel.

I have foreign key constraints set up among InnoDB tables.

My problem is that if i don't select a value in a, say, select box, the framework tries to insert or update a record in a table with '' (empty string). Which causes a MySQL error as it cannot find the equivalent foreign key value in the subtables.

Is there some elegant way to force the insertion of NULL in the foreign key fields other than checking out every single field? Or to force MySQL to accept '' as a "null" foreign key reference?

In other words: I have a, say, SELECT field with first OPTION blank. I leave the blank OPTION chosen. When I submit, an empty string '' is passed. In MySQL apparently I can do UPDATE table SET foreignKey=NULL but not UPDATE table SET foreignKey=''. It does not "convert" to NULL. I could check the fields one by one but and convert '' to NULL for every foreign key, maybe specifying all of them in an array, I was wondering if there's a more streamlined way to do this.

Maybe have to change my ON UPDATE action (which is not set) in my DB schema?

**Edit:** the columns DO accept the NULL value, the problem is in how the framework or MySQL handle the "empty value" coming from the HTML. I'm not suggesting MySQL "does it wrong", it is also logical, the problem is that you can't set a "NULL" value in HTML, and I would like to know if there's an elegant way to manage this problem in MySQL *or* Laravel.

In other words, do I have to specify manually the foreign keys and construct my query accordingly or is there another robust and elegant way?

My code so far for the model MyModel:

```
$obj = new MyModel;
$obj->fill(Input::all())); // can be all() or a subset of the request fields
$obj->save();
```

Comment: Default value empty on those columns.

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri: you're wrong, NULL is an acceptable value.

Comment: You should post the code that is being used for insertion of records.

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003: I use Laravel's model with save() and gather the fields with Input::all()

Comment: Post your code and specify the field that you want to modify to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
$obj = new MyModel;
$obj->fill(Input::all())); // can be all() or a subset of the request fields
$obj->save();
```

Use

```
$obj = new MyModel;
$obj->fieldName1 = Input::get('formField1');
$obj->fieldName2 = Input::has('formField2') && Input::get('formField2') == 'someValue' ? Input::get('formField2') :  null;
// ...
$obj->save();
```

And make sure your database `field` accepts `null` values. Also, you can set a default value as `null` from the `database/phpmyadmin`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant for "checking every single field", and the only option I tought of. I just thought there were more elegant and general ways to do it, as I came up with a nice general abstraction regarding how forms are handled. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 7):

At least since v4 of Laravel (and Eloquent models), you can use mutators (aka setters) to check if a value is empty and transform it to null, and that logic is nicely put in the model :

```php
class Anything extends \Eloquent {
    // ...
    public function setFooBarAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['foo_bar'] = empty($value)?null:$value;
    }
}
```

You can check out the [doc on mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators).

I've been oriented by this [github issue](https://github.com/FrozenNode/Laravel-Administrator/issues/475) (not exactly related but still).

Comment: This is the best way to do it in L4

Comment: Whoa, it's a long since I wrote this :) Anyway now I use mutators for these tasks, too :)

Answer (score 0):

You must remove the "not null" attribute from the field that maps your foreign key.

Comment: There is no such attribute set. Besides, the columns DO accept the NULL value, the problem is in how the framework or MySQL handle the "empty HTML value". I'm not suggesting MySQL "does it wrong", it is also logical, the problem is that you can't set a "NULL" value in HTML, and I would like to know if there's an elegant way to manage this problem.

Comment: Which framework are you using?
I removed the "not null" attribute from a mysql table and made an insert statement from mysql workbench and all worked well, leaving foreign key empty

Comment: As stated in the post, Laravel.

Comment: you're not getting the point. The problem is: I have a, say, select field with first OPTION blank. I leave the blank OPTION chosen. When I submit, an empty string '' is passed.
In MySQL apparently I can do UPDATE table SET foreignKey=NULL but not UPDATE table SET foreignKey=''. It does not "convert" to NULL.
I could check the fields one by one but and convert '' to NULL for every foreign key, maybe specifying all of them in an array, I was wondering if there's a more streamlined way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In the model add below function.

```
public function setFooBarAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['foo_bar'] = $value?:null;
}
```